# UIImagePickerController hiding status bar iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want the status bar hidden in my app. In my pList I have set:
Status Bar is initially hidden - YES
View controller-based status bar appearance - NO

This works fine until I present an UIImagePickerController. It wants to show the status bar. So in willShowViewController for the navigationController delegate I call  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES]. This does in fact hide the status bar but there is a shifting like an animation in the navigationController. I've spent some time trying to stop this animation. Anyone have any ideas how to stop it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
```

Answer (score 0):

Subclass `UIImagePickerController` and define `prefersStatusBarHidden` method, return YES if you want to hide a status bar.

Comment: I've tried that it still animates. By the way for all those who suggest using prefersStatusBarHidden in subclasses, catagories and uiviewcontrollers, that will only get called View controller-based status bar appearance is set to YES. Otherwise it never gets called.

Comment: Makes sense. How about calling setStatusBarHidden: from viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear?

Comment: I assume you are referring to the UIViewController from where the UIImagePickerController is presented. I tried that it still flickers. I have tried sub-classing UIImagePickerController and putting it in it's iewWillAppear and viewDidAppear. Still flickers. I think this is a bug in iOS 8. I have filed a Radar bug. So far no response from Apple.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this a bug in iOS 8. I filed a radar bug and Apple suggested I try the beta 8.3. With the beta I no longer see the animation.